# Excel VBA - Combining numbered list into location strings (e.g. 2.5.3.1.)

Tags: excel

is possible to get results from columns A-E into column H without use of VBA?
Do you have any suggestions how to do it? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `CONCATENATE` worksheet function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to look at the row above, so you need to paste it on row 2 and drag from there. On row 1 you will have a ref error but it will still work. For the future you may want to add an extra empty row at the top and have the formula in H2 and down.

```
H2: 

=IF(COUNT(A2:E2)=0,H1,IF(A2<>"",A2&".",LEFT(H1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(H1,".","|",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>"",0),0)-1),1))&INDEX(A2:E2,1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>"",0),0))&"."))
```

I know it looks like a mess, but I'll try to explain it:

```
IF(COUNT(A2:E2)=0,H1
```

This is for the empty rows. if empty use the one above

```
IF(A2<>"",A2&"."
```

if A2 has a value start with completely new text

```
INDEX(A2:E2<>"",0)
```

returns an array of true/false for if the cells are empty

```
MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>"",0),0)
```

This gives you the columnnumber with the new data

```
SUBSTITUTE(H1,".","|",MATCH...)
```

Repleces the n-th dot with a | This is so we can use Find to figure out how much of the text above to keep.

```
INDEX(A2:E2,1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>"",0),0))
```

is the new data

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by building up the target in a set of columns that can be hidden.

Following from your example above, if you add columns I, J, K and L, use the following formulae:

Cell I1:  `=A1 & "."`

Cell J1:  `=IF(B1="","",B1 & ".")`

Cell K1:  `=IF(C1="","",C1 & ".")`

Cell L1:  `=IF(D1="","",D1 & ".")`

All other rows:

Column I: `=IF(A2="",I1,A2 & ".")`

Column J: `=IF(B2="",IF(I2=I1,J1,""),B2 & ".")`

Column K: `=IF(C2="",IF(J2=J1,K1,""),C2 & ".")`

Column L: `=IF(D2="",IF(K2=K1,L1,""),D2 & ".")`

Then set column H to be:

```
=I1 & J1 & K1 & L1 & M1
```

This roughly translates as "If there isn't a new number, use the number from the row above, unless the parent number has changed, in which case use a blank."

You can hide columns I, J, K and L, or just use alternative columns further to the right if these are not available.